# Using the cmbright package in a limited range of my document

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

Using the cmbright package results in a complete change from serif to sans serif text and math fonts, including even lowercase, sans serif Greek letters.

However, I’d like to use the cmbright package only in a limited range of my document — for example, in the most recent edition of the *Feynman Lectures on Physics*, the cmbright package appears to be used for figures and their captions only:

[image]

How exactly can I achieve this? At the very least, I’d be interested in using the lowercase and uppercase sans serif Greek letters from the cmbright package whilst otherwise using the standard Computer Modern fonts for text and math.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `\usepackage{cmbright}`?

Comment: I want to use cmbright’s (imho) superior sans serif fonts but retain the CM serif fonts.

Comment: `cmbright` doesn't change the serif font. I suspect you want to use `cmbright` _without_ making the sans-serif font the default font.

Comment: Exactly, as described above.

Comment: I’d like cmbright NOT to turn itself into the default font for math environments, too.

Comment: So you want to be able to switch between sans math and normal math within the document?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to accomplish. :)

Comment: @campa could you please look into this again?

Comment: Uhm, I've read the question and the comments again and I'm still not completely sure about what exactly you are trying to achieve. Your chances of getting an answer would get better if you edited your question add added more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In PDFLaTeX,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
Text in Computer Modern Roman,
\textsf{and Computer Modern Bright.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern Roman and Bright sample]

To change only the sans-serif text font, and not the default font or the math fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\begin{document}
Text in Computer Modern Roman,
\textsf{and Computer Modern Bright.}
\end{document}
```

Then add `\sffamily` to every type of text you want to appear in sans-serif, such as captions.

If you wanted to use CM Bright Greek letters in math mode, the simplest way to do that is probably to load it as the OML sans-serif math alphabet through `isomath`.

You could also do something like (untested):

```
\DeclareSymbolFont        {sans} {OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont      {sans}{bold} {OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{sans}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{sans}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{sans}{15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{sans}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{sans}{20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{sans}{21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{sans}{22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{sans}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{sans}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{sans}{27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{sans}{28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{sans}{29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{sans}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{sans}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{sans}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{sans}{38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{sans}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{sans}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{sans}{3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{sans}{6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{sans}{7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{sans}{9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{sans}{10}
```

In LuaTeX or XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\setsansfont{CMU Bright}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
Text in Computer Modern Roman,
\textsf{and Computer Modern Bright.}
\end{document}
```

To load only its Greek letters in math mode, you would do something like:

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{CMU Bright}[range=up/{Greek,greek}]
\setmathfont{CMU Bright Italic}[range=it/{Greek,greek}]
```

Comment: This leaves the math fonts sans serif, however. How can I reset the math fonts to serif when using the cmbright package?

Comment: @JilalJahangir Edited with that use case.